# Google Drive API create and download PDF

Tags: google-drive-api, pdf-generation

Is it possible to call the Google Drive API, create a document based on a template with dynamic data sent from an app that is not a Google Apps Scripts app, and download the document as a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Google Drive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents), The Drive API allows you to download files that are stored in Google Drive. Also, you can download exported versions of Google Documents (Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc.) in formats that your app can handle. Drive also supports providing users direct access to a file via the URL in the `webViewLink` property.

Here is an example code that demonstrate on how to download a Google Document in PDF format using the client libraries:

```
String fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, "application/pdf")
.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Also check this [page](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/) for more information.

Comment: Yes, that was my example as well. But I asked actually another question, which is how to influence the export. So with your code, it actually converts the entire document to a PDF, but from the entire spreadsheet I would like to a) define the workbooks (only interested in a subset) and b) I want to export the document in landscape mode

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has instructions on [doing this via an HTTP request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export). However, it is silent on doing it via the Drive V3 Python API.

I found the solution in this video [Google Drive API: Uploading & Downloading Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7YH6rdR-tk), released by the official Google Developers YouTube channel.

This example assumes that you have a file created and that you have the authorization setup.

```
# setup authorization
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

file_id = 'your-file-id'

data = DRIVE.files().export(fileId=file_id, mimeType="application/pdf").execute()
if data:
    filename = 'your-file-name.pdf'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_file.write(data)
```

The file will be downloaded in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering, if by using that API you can also define which Workbook you want to retrieve and whether the export should be portrait or landscape.

I found out, that you can set key (string)/value (object) settings to the request, but it actually does not work.

Anybody knows how to fine-tune the export via the API. If I am logged in, I can do it via a simple HTTP Get like that (below), but how to do it with the API?

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=<spreadheetIDHere>&exportFormat=pdf&gid=<workbookIdHere>
```

best,
fri